# Google People API listDirectoryPeople is not returning names for any users in the directory

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-people-api

The api found here:

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople

with a readmask of `metadata, names, emailAddresses`

is not returning names for any of the users in the directory anymore using the interface found on that page. It used to return names this is a change in the last week. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide information about which parameters you are setting? Specifically, what `source` are you setting, among [DirectorySourceType](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/DirectorySourceType)?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and the example on the reference documentation requesting names does not working either. 

https://developers.google.com/people/v1/directory#protocol
  
This looks like a a defect in the listDirectoryPeople API.

Answer (score 0):

I opened [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920897/google-people-api-listdirectorypeople-is-not-returning-names-for-some-users-in-t) with a related problem.

This solution works to me: you have to register to [Google Currents](https://currents.google.com/) in order to get your name for your user.

I hope that this serves to you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a known bug with Google's API.  [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70603003/google-people-api-directory-contacts-cannot-get-name-field-from-api) talks about it, and the issue is [tracked here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196235775?pli=1) by Google.

Comment: why didn't you flag the question as a duplicate then?

Comment: @starball I feel like this is a better question, its simple and to-the-point, easy to read, and actually uses the keyword "listDirectoryPeople" so its easier to find.

Comment: then flag that question as a duplicate of this.

Comment: @starball that question has a good answer.  After reading [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) I figured that its okay to have two similar questions if they each provide their own value, which I think is the case here.