# Google People API listDirectoryPeople is not returning names for some users in the directory

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I am working with the People API listDirectoryPeople and I am stuck with this problem. For some users, attribute names are retrieved, but not for others.

The authenthication is not a problem because this project is in Google Apps Script and I am using the People service.

With this [API request](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople?apix_params=%7B%22pageSize%22%3A200%2C%22readMask%22%3A%22names%22%2C%22sources%22%3A%5B%22DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE%22%5D%7D) executed I get a response as following:

```
{"people": [{"resourceName": "people/117652981masked","etag": "masked"},{"resourceName": "people/10883742masked","etag": "masked"},{"resourceName": "people/103089448masked","etag": "masked","names": [{"metadata": {"primary": true,"source": {"type": "PROFILE","id": "10308944877masked"}},"displayName": "masked","familyName": "masked","givenName": "masked","displayNameLastFirst": "masked","unstructuredName": "masked"}]}, ... }
```

If I only request emailAddressed or photo, the information is correct.

Do you know if there is something wrong in our GSuite domain configuration? or is there a bug in this api related?

This question is related to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65801879/google-people-api-listdirectorypeople-is-not-returning-names-for-any-users-in-th) but is not the same question. Maybe it is the same bug/problem, but I don't know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: people api is going to require that someone added the information in Google contacts.  It can only return the information it has.

Comment: I though this api will represent the directory of this page: https://contacts.google.com/

So, this information is not filled in contacts api and therefore people api cannot recover it?

Thanks for the answer, by the way :)

Comment: Are all the users in the same domain? @asegnz

Comment: Yes, they are. I solve this issue and I'm writing the answer. Thanks ale13

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved by registering at [Currents](https://currents.google.com), the new Google+. When I registered, I got my name.

Thanks for the support.

Comment: I have registered at currents and I still don't get the name. Do I have to wait a while?