# Google People API - Directory Contacts - Cannot get name field from API

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-people-api

We are using *People API* to fetch details from *Directory* . The API is not returning the name for most of the people in the directory. 2 accounts in our GSuite account alone provide the name field, while the others don't. However, other details like *emailAddresses* and *phoneNumbers* are available for everyone.

We didn't find any finer grained control for individual fields when using the setting *External Directory Sharing → Domain and public data*

We tried to change the setting from default to *External Directory Sharing → Public data and authenticated user basic profile fields*. However, this results in API response showing **PERMISSION_DENIED** error.

For one of the users in directory, we created Google Currents account. When the account was created and active, the name field became available for this user. After the account was deleted/deactivated, the name field was no longer available.

People API being used:

GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:searchDirectoryPeople?query=a&sources=DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_CONTACT&sources=DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE&readMask=emailAddresses,names,phoneNumbers,photos

The docs we have referred to so far are as follows:

People API - Search Directory:
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchDirectoryPeople

Let third-party apps access Directory data:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6343701

A merged view of people information:
https://developers.google.com/people/#a_merged_view_of_people_information

Edit:

cURL command:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:searchDirectoryPeople?query=s&sources=DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_CONTACT&sources=DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE&readMask=emailAddresses,names,phoneNumbers,photos' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <access-token>'
```

Comment: Can you show your code? On whose behalf are you performing your request? As an admin? Can you see any difference between the accounts with and without provided name field?

Comment: Have you tried the API explorer here https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople?  I would experiment with this.

Comment: @ziganotschka The API can be called on behalf of any user. I tested with both admin and non-admin user. Result was the same.

The name field was returned for users who had created `Google Currents` account.

I will update the post with the cURL command.

Comment: @sdbol I tried with API explorer too. The result was the same.

Comment: What type of users would you like to search for? Users of your domain or domain-wide shared contacts of your domain (obtaining information for private contacts is not possible)? You specified two sources in your curl request - I do not think this is possible. Also, keep in mind that `query=s` will only return users with an `s` in one of the person fields.

Comment: I am trying to get information for all users listed at:
https://contacts.google.com/directory.

In the [guide](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/directory#search_the_directory_people) also two sources are specified.

I also tried with different queries. The result is always missing the name. Please note that other fields like email and photo are available for users. It seems something to do with the `name` field visibility.

Comment: This is trange, I can see the names for all contacts where I can see the emails. Since you have a Workspace domain, you can contact the [Admin support](https://support.google.com/a/?hl=en#topic=4388346). They can have a look for you to see if there is something wrong with your settings.

Comment: Yeah, API behavior is strange. Thanks for the help. I'll check with the support team.

Comment: @Patrick I didn't find a workaround. The API returns the names only if the user's profile is public. It seems to be a privacy protection feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with the People API.

You can find it here in Google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196235775?pli=1. **If this bug is impacting you, I highly suggest you leave a comment letting the team know you're currently facing the issue and leave a +1 by clicking the "+1" button on the top right.**

In the comment section of this question, it was suggested that this behavior is to be expected and is related to privacy. It's safe to say that's not the case as 1. the issue was accepted as a bug by the Google team, and 2. all other information is successfully returned from the API aside from this field.

### Additional information on the resolution

Back in August of 2022, the Google team explained the fix was being held up by a bigger effort:

> Hello there - apologize for the delay, we did identify the root cause,
> however the fix is blocked on another bigger effort. We recently
> started making progress on the blocking issue, and will provide an ETA
> as soon as we figure out some of the unknowns for the solution.

However, recently (January 17th, 2023), the bug was assigned to someone at Google. This may suggest that the bigger effort was completed and that the team is now unblocked.

### Potential workaround

Hopefully the bug is fixed soon. But in case we're waiting for a while, these workarounds may help.

Email is reliably returned for all directory users. The OP doesn't mention the exact context in which he or she is using the API, but for some applications you might be able to get away with using email (e.g. if you're just trying to identify the Directory user to the end user).

Additionally, if user email addresses in your directory follow a uniform formatting, you should be able to parse those to get the name. This is the workaround I'm currently using. E.g.

`john.smith@example.com` -> `John Smith`

`jsmith@example.com` -> `J. Smith`

`jsmith3@example.com` -> `J. Smith` (if you're at a large organization, you may have to remove some numbers)

### Meta Sidenote

Yes, it's valid to post that something is a known bug as an answer. Check out this link if you have questions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369622/1101602.