# Google API's directory_people does not return names for People instances other than API Caller

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I'm working on an integration in ruby with Google that needs to retrieve the people in a Google user's directory (after having accepted the appropriate OAuth scope). This is using the people API's directory_people request with the readMask = "emailAddresses,names" All the requested people instances are returned as expected with their email addresses present, however all the instances are returned with a nil name value except for the record matching the API caller (I can get my own people instance's name but no one elses).

Previously this logic used elsewhere in the codebase worked fine (all names returned as expected) but there's seems to have been a change of some sort with the API I think causing this new behavior. My google workspace manager has confirmed we have not made any changes on our end to cause this. We have tried promoting my google account to super admin in the google workspace to see if that resolved the issue but still, all names are missing except my own when I make the API call myself.

I did see one relevant post already [Google People API listDirectoryPeople is not returning names for any users in the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65801879/google-people-api-listdirectorypeople-is-not-returning-names-for-any-users-in-th) where it says you need to enable Currents for your workspace.  I had that change made (Currents was enabled for the workspace, and myself and another user both signedup for it) but it hasn't changed the behavior for the API as only my name is coming back for all the people instances.

Does anyone know about this problem and how it can be resolved? Thanks!

EDIT: Full request in Ruby Code below (for a Google People api instance for my authorized user)

```
        response = list_person_directory_people(
          page_size: limit, # NOTE: 1000 is max supported value for this api
          read_mask: 'emailAddresses,names,photos',
          sources:   ['DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE']
        )

        response&.people
```

Comment: Can you provide your full request?

Comment: Added to post body thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not able to repro this on my account, I have contacts being returned with no problem. Does the same behaviour occur for other users on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, it occurs for anyone in my google workspace domain that I run this against AND it seems to occur for our customers in other google workspaces too.

Comment: It is a known bug with the Google API.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70603003/google-people-api-directory-contacts-cannot-get-name-field-from-api

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/directory) there's a note about this:

> Important: Reading domain data requires that the domain admin must
> have [enabled external contact and profile sharing](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6343701) of domain-scoped
> data for their domain.

This admin setting might be the cause for this issue

Comment: Thanks @marmor, I had my Workspace Admin take a look and it seems that this setting is already enabled (contact sharing = ON, external_directory_sharin = "Domain and public Data"). Names are still not returned though.